# Converting shapefile into raster with desired pixels 1km²

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, rasterization, pixel

I have one shapefile and I want to convert into 1km by 1km pixels in QGIS. Because my raster image is of same resolution so I want to merge and see how many houses are in one cell. I rasterize my tiff file. When I do conversion vector to raster it give me this error. I checked my unit its in degree so how can I change it from degree to meter to resolve this issue.

By default its CRS EPSG:4326- WGS84

[image] this issue.

Comment: Reproject your raster to a coordinate system with units in meters

Answer (score 2):

Your question in lacking details like whether you want to use an attribute as raster value or specify it manually.

In both cases, search for ["Rasterize"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster):

[image]

If you want the pixels to overlap exactly with your other raster, use that raster as extent layer.

Comment: When I try by vector to raster conversion it give me this error. I add picture in my question.

Comment: Read the error message, you havent chosen output raster size units